# What can cause JavaScript and CSS files to be minified?

Tags: css, javascript, optimization

On one of my client's site, I see that my plugin's JS and CSS files are minified.

Trying to identify what causes the files to minify, I tried to deactivate all plugins (except mine), and changing the theme to TwentyEleven. However, the files were still minified.

What else could cause the files to be minified?

Comment: Where do the minified files reside? Has there been a plugin such as W3TC active?

Comment: @vancoder: The minified files are in `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/.../my-jsfile.js`. I'm not sure whether the W3TC plugin was active in the past. I can't see it in the list of the plugins.

Comment: are u using mu-plugin folder?

Comment: of course, this is my plugin's folder.

Comment: Hmm, possibly it's being automatically minified server-side. Check the host's control panel? I assume there isn't a CDN involved? If there is, check the settings there too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your hosting environment to see if they've enabled something like mod_pagespeed?

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod